# How to change the name of "my company" that gets auto logged for games

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a simple 3d platformer in unity. I found out it auto logs some stuff in the /users/username/AppData/LocalLow folder. It logged it in the folder titled "DefaultCompany".

Now, that's a pretty odd name and I'd like to change it. How would I do that?

I tried looking in the "build options" but found nothing.

Comment: See the [official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Build Settings Menue go to Player Settings and navigate to Player. There you can change the company name.[image: Access Player Settings]

[image: Access Player and change the Company Name]

Comment: Thank you so very much for answering this obviously stupid question. It was right there. I hope it can help anyone else like me :)